# Application of integration, confusion.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am reading a research paper and I could not understand how the author derived the final equation using integration.

Equation A:

$Y_L=\frac{1}{1-\beta}\left [\displaystyle\int_0^{N_L}x_L(j)^{1-\beta}\,dj\right ]L^{\beta }$

Equation B:

$x_L=\left [\frac{p_L}{\chi_L(j)}\right ]^{1/\beta}L$

Equation C:

$Y_L=\frac{1}{1-\beta}p_L^{\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}}N_LL$

where,

- $N_L$ is the number of varieties of machines
- $x_L$ is the range of machines, so $x_L(j)$ is a machine type $(j)$
- $\chi_L(j)$ is the price of machine type $(j)$

The author uses the equation B in equation A and derives the equation C after integration. It appears, the author replaces $x_L(j)$ in equation A with the equation for $x_L$ which is the equation B. Can anyone please help understand how this could be done?

Comment: There's no way that you've defined enough notation here for this to be feasible.  For instance: you replace $x_L(j)$ by an expression in terms of $\chi_L(j)$; but, for that to integrate out, you must have some idea what $\chi_L(j)$ is.

Comment: It looks like the author has set $\chi_{L}$ to 1 (maybe an approximation ?). Then the result would follow.

Comment: @NickPeterson, I've described the variables in some details. Will you please have a look? Thanks.

Comment: @JohannesTrost, can you please type your answer and explain, then I will accept if correct. Not sure what is correct at this stage. About setting the variable to 1. The author does not mention this though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
I made a mistake: I assumed that $\chi_{L}(j)$ is independent of $N_{L}$. I edited the post accordingly in **bold**.

After inserting B into A, we get
$$
Y_{L} = \frac{1}{1-\beta} L \left[\int_{0}^{N_{L}}\left[\frac{p_{L}}{\chi_{L}(j)} \right]^{\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}} d j\right]=\frac{p_{L}^{\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}}}{1-\beta}L \left[\int_{0}^{N_{L}}\left[\frac{1}{\chi_{L}(j)} \right]^{\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}} d j\right].
$$
This would match equation C, if the integral on the right equals $N_{L}$. **Assuming that $\chi_{L}(j)$ is independent of $N_{L}$,** the integral evaluates to $N_{L}$ only, if the integrand equalled 1 for the whole integration range, which makes it necessary that $\chi_{L}$ is constant and equal to 1 (assuming that $\chi_{L}$ and $\beta$ are real numbers).

**However, if we allow $\chi_{L}(j)$ to depend on $N_{L}$ a lot of functions may apply.**

Comment: Many thanks, can you replace $x_L(j)$ with $x_L$?